# Confusion in understanding methods in android

Tags: android, service, onpause

I want to play audio on lock screen and I know for this I have to use service. But I am little confused So I have following questions.

1. I want to know on home and back button press which method is called i.e. onPause or onStop?
2. If my app running and someone call me and I pick the call then which method is called i.e. onPause or onStop?
3. On screen lock which method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On home press: onPause->onStop. On back press: onBackPressed->onPause->onStop->onDestroy
2. Same as pressing home essentially.
3. Same as 2.

Comment: In option 2 i have mistake now i updated please see.

Comment: But in this case which method called by default?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. Could you please be more precise?

Comment: I am considering your answer as correct but if ever you find any strange behaviour in calling methods please let me know also.

Comment: And please see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986283/how-to-play-sound-using-service-in-android

Answer (score 2):

first onPause() will be called for each of your question and onStop() will be called when another activity comes in foreground and your previous one goes in background.

The Basic difference is that when onStop() called the previous activity in not visible and new activity comes in foreground and overlap the previous one.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

[image: Lifecycle]