# How to play sound using service in android

Tags: android, audio, service

I want to play sound in my android app. And maybe I have to use service for this. But [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986012/confusion-in-understanding-methods-in-android) I see on home `button` pressed and on screen lock `onPause` method called. But in case of home button pressed I want to stop sound in case of screen lock i dont want to stop sound. So how to do this and how to use `onPause` method in this case?

Please someone help me. Thanks...

Comment: It's hard to imagine your use case. Will the user expect such a behaviour? The fact that you handle these events in callbacks like `onPause` and `onStop` is here to abstract the reason why your app is not in foreground anymore, because it's not really supposed to behave differently

Comment: Anyway, if you really want to distinguish, maybe you could look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7331905/1540818

Comment: You will need to be clearer about your stop / don't stop cases.  For example, what should happen if the user navigates away to another Activity, potentially from another app?

Answer (score 1):

Use **MediaPlayer** from Android. See: [Android Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```